# How to convert text to csv from linux?

Tags: text

```
azureuser@puppetagent-ubuntu1:/tmp$ cat /bin/user_activity.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo `last` > /tmp/login_history.txt
```

I'm tracking user data in linux through the "last" command so I'm appending data to .txt and .csv files but still data is not coming as format as i'm expecting.

**`cat out.txt`:**

```
azureuse pts/1 157.47.38.139 Mon Sep 20 14:30 still logged in 
azureuse pts/0 157.47.56.225 Mon Sep 20 12:33 - 14:34 (02:00) azureuse pts/0 157.47.56.225 Mon Sep 20 10:29 - 12:33 (02:03) azureuse pts/0 157.47.56.225 Mon Sep 20 09:53 - 10:28 (00:35) azureuse pts/0 157.47.37.28 Mon Sep 20 09:09 - 09:53 (00:43) azureuse pts/1 157.47.40.253 Mon Sep 20 05:30 - 08:51 (03:20) azureuse pts/0 157.47.40.253 Mon Sep 20 05:28 - 08:51 (03:22) azureuse pts/0 157.48.201.134 Fri Sep 17 12:15 - 16:10 (03:54) azureuse pts/0 157.48.201.134 Fri Sep 17 08:47 - 11:38 (02:50) azureuse pts/0 157.48.201.134 Fri Sep 17 06:07 - 08:17 (02:09) azureuse pts/0 157.48.139.114 Thu Sep 16 14:53 - 14:57 (00:04) azureuse pts/0 157.48.139.114 Thu Sep 16 14:48 - 14:48 (00:00) azureuse pts/0 157.48.139.114 Thu Sep 16 13:49 - 14:47 (00:58) reboot system boot 5.8.0-1041-azure Thu Sep 16 13:29 still running wtmp begins Thu Sep 16 13:29:48 2021
```

im expecting like below

```
testvm:/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/manifests$ last
 azureuse pts/0        104.46.119.134   Mon Sep 20 14:29   still logged in
 azureuse pts/1        104.46.119.134   Mon Sep 20 09:52 - 14:35  (04: 42)
 azureuse pts/0        104.46.119.134   Mon Sep 20 09:10 - 09:53  (00:42)
```

Comment: Apologies, but could you [edit] your question to fix the formatting? I tried to do it for you, but the first bit does not match the third bit, and the blockquote in the middle seems copy/pasted from 3 different sources. Be sure to also include the version of Ubuntu that you are running, as this makes it easier to provide specific suggestions.

Comment: "*not coming as format as i'm expecting*". What format do you expect? Please add example output. And also tell us what you tried.

Comment: expecting comma separated values like as csv

Comment: I can see why you would like it, but the format provided by `last` is just normal text with a space character between each field.  So, in your example, there is a space character between `134` and `Mon` and between `Mon` and `Sep`.  If you need it separated, then you have to write a program to parse it yourself....

Comment: It is normal text only but at the same time I want to put the same text into the file when appending into the file all the data gets fixed. So I don't want that .Is there a way to achieve the same.?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `utmpdump` to dump `/var/log/wtmp`:

```bsh
utmpdump < /var/log/wtmp | IFS=\] mapfile -d \[; a=("${MAPFILE[@]%% *}"); IFS=,; for ((i=0; i<${#a[@]}; i+=8)); do echo "${a[*]:$i:8}"; done
```